# FFMPEG Concat with Videos in millisecond Length results in broken Video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I am using this List of Videos for Concatination in FFMPEG:

```
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\0dcd83e6-1931-4bf1-87f0-211c758050f3.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:07.4890000
outpoint 00:00:07.7250000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\0dcd83e6-1931-4bf1-87f0-211c758050f3.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:01.6300000
outpoint 00:00:01.8660000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\0dcd83e6-1931-4bf1-87f0-211c758050f3.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:12.7170000
outpoint 00:00:12.9530000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\0dcd83e6-1931-4bf1-87f0-211c758050f3.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:05.6260000
outpoint 00:00:05.8620000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\0dcd83e6-1931-4bf1-87f0-211c758050f3.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:49.5930000
outpoint 00:00:49.8290000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\0dcd83e6-1931-4bf1-87f0-211c758050f3.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:50.3050000
outpoint 00:00:50.5410000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\18c1a3cc-5817-4676-a01b-18cc72f9dad7.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:28.1420000
outpoint 00:00:28.6830000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\18c1a3cc-5817-4676-a01b-18cc72f9dad7.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:08.0820000
outpoint 00:00:08.6230000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\18c1a3cc-5817-4676-a01b-18cc72f9dad7.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:18.6850000
outpoint 00:00:19.2260000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\1af968d4-a6e9-4c44-a6d9-c6c06bb8631a.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:22.3670000
outpoint 00:00:22.5140000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\1af968d4-a6e9-4c44-a6d9-c6c06bb8631a.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:03.4820000
outpoint 00:00:03.6290000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\1af968d4-a6e9-4c44-a6d9-c6c06bb8631a.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:40.2620000
outpoint 00:00:40.4090000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\1af968d4-a6e9-4c44-a6d9-c6c06bb8631a.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:49.5600000
outpoint 00:00:49.7070000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\1af968d4-a6e9-4c44-a6d9-c6c06bb8631a.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:20.4010000
outpoint 00:00:20.5480000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\1af968d4-a6e9-4c44-a6d9-c6c06bb8631a.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:30.4620000
outpoint 00:00:30.6090000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\1af968d4-a6e9-4c44-a6d9-c6c06bb8631a.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:40.8190000
outpoint 00:00:40.9660000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\1af968d4-a6e9-4c44-a6d9-c6c06bb8631a.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:03.5130000
outpoint 00:00:03.6600000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\1af968d4-a6e9-4c44-a6d9-c6c06bb8631a.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:20.0250000
outpoint 00:00:20.1720000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\22c3c2e2-4ab9-4ced-ada0-48eaeb4d0854.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:07.8730000
outpoint 00:00:08.2310000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\22c3c2e2-4ab9-4ced-ada0-48eaeb4d0854.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:02.9720000
outpoint 00:00:03.3300000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\22c3c2e2-4ab9-4ced-ada0-48eaeb4d0854.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:15.0240000
outpoint 00:00:15.3820000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\22c3c2e2-4ab9-4ced-ada0-48eaeb4d0854.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:14.9730000
outpoint 00:00:15.3310000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\22c3c2e2-4ab9-4ced-ada0-48eaeb4d0854.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:10.9450000
outpoint 00:00:11.3030000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\22c3c2e2-4ab9-4ced-ada0-48eaeb4d0854.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:12.3510000
outpoint 00:00:12.7090000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\61c509e8-efbf-4697-872a-dc288e5ae8d3.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:06.7640000
outpoint 00:00:07.0580000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\61c509e8-efbf-4697-872a-dc288e5ae8d3.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:38.3440000
outpoint 00:00:38.6380000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\61c509e8-efbf-4697-872a-dc288e5ae8d3.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:01.6260000
outpoint 00:00:01.9200000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\61c509e8-efbf-4697-872a-dc288e5ae8d3.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:01.8380000
outpoint 00:00:02.1320000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\61c509e8-efbf-4697-872a-dc288e5ae8d3.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:06.9730000
outpoint 00:00:07.2670000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a3041f6-7eba-4473-bd5c-2cf05f31e62c.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:38.4000000
outpoint 00:00:38.5950000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a3041f6-7eba-4473-bd5c-2cf05f31e62c.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:12.3260000
outpoint 00:00:12.5210000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a3041f6-7eba-4473-bd5c-2cf05f31e62c.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:23.9310000
outpoint 00:00:24.1260000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a3041f6-7eba-4473-bd5c-2cf05f31e62c.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:39.6420000
outpoint 00:00:39.8370000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a3041f6-7eba-4473-bd5c-2cf05f31e62c.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:06.5000000
outpoint 00:00:06.6950000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a3041f6-7eba-4473-bd5c-2cf05f31e62c.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:43.1100000
outpoint 00:00:43.3050000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a3041f6-7eba-4473-bd5c-2cf05f31e62c.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:52.4960000
outpoint 00:00:52.6910000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a3041f6-7eba-4473-bd5c-2cf05f31e62c.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:34.0990000
outpoint 00:00:34.2940000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a3041f6-7eba-4473-bd5c-2cf05f31e62c.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:33.3750000
outpoint 00:00:33.5700000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a769a1c-9ba7-4d59-bbea-f91fddb962a0.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:37.3980000
outpoint 00:00:37.9280000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a769a1c-9ba7-4d59-bbea-f91fddb962a0.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:25.1330000
outpoint 00:00:25.6630000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a769a1c-9ba7-4d59-bbea-f91fddb962a0.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:22.3130000
outpoint 00:00:22.8430000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a7951aa-70c8-4943-a059-a02264e82ddc.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:35.4570000
outpoint 00:00:35.6000000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a7951aa-70c8-4943-a059-a02264e82ddc.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:07.5190000
outpoint 00:00:07.6620000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a7951aa-70c8-4943-a059-a02264e82ddc.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:38.3690000
outpoint 00:00:38.5120000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a7951aa-70c8-4943-a059-a02264e82ddc.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:58.3520000
outpoint 00:00:58.4950000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a7951aa-70c8-4943-a059-a02264e82ddc.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:21.8970000
outpoint 00:00:22.0400000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a7951aa-70c8-4943-a059-a02264e82ddc.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:57.4000000
outpoint 00:00:57.5430000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a7951aa-70c8-4943-a059-a02264e82ddc.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:10.0960000
outpoint 00:00:10.2390000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a7951aa-70c8-4943-a059-a02264e82ddc.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:32.0420000
outpoint 00:00:32.1850000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a7951aa-70c8-4943-a059-a02264e82ddc.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:39.9040000
outpoint 00:00:40.0470000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8a7951aa-70c8-4943-a059-a02264e82ddc.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:03.7370000
outpoint 00:00:03.8800000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8cc0daf7-affd-4e16-bd2b-31727829b9eb.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:23.5900000
outpoint 00:00:23.7960000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8cc0daf7-affd-4e16-bd2b-31727829b9eb.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:39.9760000
outpoint 00:00:40.1820000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8cc0daf7-affd-4e16-bd2b-31727829b9eb.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:25.0120000
outpoint 00:00:25.2180000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8cc0daf7-affd-4e16-bd2b-31727829b9eb.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:32.9350000
outpoint 00:00:33.1410000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8cc0daf7-affd-4e16-bd2b-31727829b9eb.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:25.0670000
outpoint 00:00:25.2730000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8cc0daf7-affd-4e16-bd2b-31727829b9eb.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:13.9150000
outpoint 00:00:14.1210000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\8cc0daf7-affd-4e16-bd2b-31727829b9eb.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:49.3900000
outpoint 00:00:49.5960000
file 'C:\Work\test\RandomUpwardShots\9ce865a0-4c34-478e-9952-72e4c280daf7.mp4'
inpoint 00:00:27.2750000
outpoint 00:00:28.0520000
```

And this command in CLI:

`ffmpeg -y -safe 0 -f concat -i outputFile.txt -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v copy outputFile.mp4`

And I get this Video as a result:
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/gG4GG-0gIqw

The Points why I call this broken:

- Audio has clearly some scrubbing to it
- The Video is playing under Windows (VLC-Player) but the Audio is "gone" after the first Clip
- The Video shows clearly some Fragments under Windows and you can't see anything

(For Point 2 and 3 this is not visible in the Youtube-Video. Sadly I dont know why. But I also dont know how to share the resulting video...)

Is there anything to clear this up? Is there a way to re-encode the separate Clips after cutting them with FFMPEG?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the solution.

The resulting Video contains just too much action to be handled by any of my video players.

This is not happening because Youtube is trying to render the video down to a usable format.

Hope this will help anyone else.